# codeigniter base url not working correctly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just launched a new site and  I have the base url as:

> $config['base_url']     = 'http://x.com/';

which works but when i go to www.x.com in my browser I get page not found error.
When I set the base url to 'http://www.x.com/'. Now the site does not work anymore.
Does anyone know how to fix this? I am lost on how to get this going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you actually have an issue with your [`VirtualHost`s](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html). That would explain why you're getting 404's. Try adding this to your httpd.conf or equivalent and then restart Apache:

```
# Place this in the virtualhost listening to x.com.
ServerAlias www.x.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http';
if (isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) && $_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on"){
    $config['base_url'] .= "s";
}
$config['base_url'] .= "://";
if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]!= "80"){
    $config['base_url'] .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"];
}else{
    $config['base_url'] .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
}

$config["base_url"]."/";
```